# Gherkin - Include common steps in many scenarios (Codeception)

Tags: php, bdd, codeception, gherkin

I'm using gherkin driven by codeception for BDD in my project. I would like to test if user given with a role is able to see menu entry points which are suitable for him.

At this moment I use this scenario:

```
Scenario: basic menu check
   User "foo" has role "basic_user"
   Given I am logged in as "foo" with password "Test123!"
   Then I should see "Project" menu point
   And I should see "Settings" menu point
   And I should see "Notifications" menu point
   And I should see "Messages" menu point
   And I should see "Logout" menu point
   Then I logout
```

I would like to reuse 3 steps many times:

```
   And I should see "Settings" menu point
   And I should see "Notifications" menu point
   And I should see "Messages" menu point
```

I do not want to copy&paste it every time I create new scenario. Instead I want to write it as... lets say include file (also in gherkin language), and use it in my scenarios:

```
Scenario: basic menu check
   ...
   Include "common_menu_check"
   ...
```

Is it possible? How I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Kyle's answer I'd rather prefer to rewrite scenarios like in your example using table as multiline argument in the following way:

```
Scenario: basic menu check
   User "foo" has role "basic_user"
   Given I am logged in as "foo" with password "Test123!"
   Then I should see menu points:
   | Settings      |  
   | Notifications |  
   | Messages      |  
   | Logout        |  
   Then I logout
```

It is less imperative and more human-friendly ("I should see" in every line is too boring) so it would be easier to discuss with customer.

Note that here table used as multiline argument, not as Example. See about table as multiline argument for steps here:

- Codeception: http://codeception.com/docs/07-BDD#Tables
- Cucumber: https://cucumber.io/docs/reference#data-tables
- Behat: http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/1.gherkin.html

Comment: `Then I should see menu points:` . Does this follow the concept of `examples`?

Comment: It this case it is not gherkin example, it is table argument for step. 

See http://codeception.com/docs/07-BDD#Tables (https://cucumber.io/docs/reference#data-tables for Cucumber and http://docs.behat.org/en/v2.5/guides/1.gherkin.html#tables for Behat)

Comment: This is a great addition. Using them in conjunction would also mean greater human readability, and the need to copy-paste would be reduced.

`Then I should see the common menu points
And I should see the the menu points:
| Project   |
| Logout   |`

Would be nice on the eyes (when formatted correctly in a feature file, of course)

Answer (score 2):

Why couldn't you write a new step?

```
/**
 *
 * @Then /^I should see the common menu points$/
 */
public function iShouldSeeTheCommonMenuPoints()
{
   // CODE HERE FOR SEEING MENU ITEMS
}
```

And then use this step in your feature file:

```
Scenario: basic menu check
    User "foo" has role "basic_user"
Given I am logged in as "foo" with password "Test123!"
Then I should see the common menu points
And I should see "Project" menu point
And I should see "Logout" menu point
Then I logout
```

Comment: Because i would like to manage `iShouldSeeTheCommonMenuPoints` functionality with gherkin syntax

Comment: It isn't something that _should_ be done. The functionality has been removed from the majority of cucumber-based frameworks as it is considered bad practice. Saying that, in theory you should be able to include the function of `iShouldSeeMenuPoint()` in the file that you define `iShouldSeeTheCommonMenuPoints()`, and use it in the new step. This will retain your functionality, without being bad practice, and would mean that you'd be able to manage `iShouldSeeTheCommonMenuPoints` from the same function that the gherkin would have came from.